# Filter json by value of a key in JSONPath

Tags: jsonpath

I'm having this json:

```
{
  "paths": {
      "foo": {
          "key": 1
      },
      "bar": {
          "key": 2
      }
  }
}
```

I would like to use `JSONPath` to find element "foo" by its name ("foo")

I tried something like `$.paths.*.[?(~=='foo')]` but it does not seem to work (I checked on https://jsonpath.com)

Comment: Find element "foo" based on what? Its name? As the parent of "key: 1"? The first child of "paths"?

Comment: by its name - "foo"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the to find the element by its name, this expression

```
$.paths.foo
```

outputs

```
[
    {
        "key": 1
    }
]
```